# Select column names where row values are not null pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a sample dataframe:-

```
 A      B    C
23     45  30
54     39  NaN
NaN    45  76
87     32  NaN
```

I want a list (or list of lists) that contains column names where row values are not NaN.

Expected Output:-

```
A B C
A B
B C
A B
```

What is the right way of doing this?
Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a [`.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) product of `df.columns` with [`df.notna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html):

```
df.notna().dot(df.columns+',').str.rstrip(',') #you can assign to a new column
```

---

```
0    A,B,C
1      A,B
2      B,C
3      A,B
dtype: object
```

Comment: Man wish I could upvote this answer more than once. Smart way of using the matrix multiplication.